# Flex regex multy line comment

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008, bison, lex, flex-lexer

Can someone explain to me the difference,i've been testing for over 2 hours now...

```
 This regex \"(.|\n)*\" gets everything inside " " (along with the " ").

 This regex "//".*$ gets a single line comment(c).

`But the regex \/\*(.|\n)*\*\/ doesn't get a multy line comment
```

instead it gets too many, i don't even understand. Can someone explain to me the difference?Also [^"] means everything except " is it possible to write [^*/] or it takes * and / as not connected characters?By the way i run all these on VS2008(using flex and bison). I found examples that doesn't work on VS2008, so if someone knows a really good site that explains regex share it with me cause i feel like i'm lost in a labyrinth.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

try using below regEx to get the commented part along with start and end block of comment :

```
b = /\/\*(.)*(\n)?(.)*\*\/g
```

e.g

```
a = "some of my text/* hello this is comment\nthis comment is not good*/. Text cont."
b = /\/\*(.)*(\n)?(.)*\*\/g
a.replace(b, "")
[output ] : "some of my text. Text cont."
```

hope this will help you.

this expression is for JS.  I think in your case you should try

```
"\/\*((.)*(\n)?)*(.)*\*\/"
```

Comment: Thank you for answearing.I've never used any like b = regeg or a.replace. Anyway i tried to /\/\*(.)*(\n)?(.)*\*\//g this on my code and it sais "Error 1 error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Generating lexical analyser..." Project3 Project3
"

Comment: regex updated in previous there was a error. correct is /\/*(.)*(\n)?(.)**\/g

Comment: Thank you for your time again. I tried everything, the only one that doesn't have an error is this "\/\*(.)*(\n)?(.)*\*\/" but it does nothing. :/

Comment: I think pasting in comment is deleting some part sorry for that.
"\/\\*(.)*(\n)?(.)*\\*\/" try this one as updated in answer last line

Comment: \/\*(.)*(\n)?(.)*\*\/ indeed works but only for 1 line /*comment*/ it doesn't support multiline comments.

Comment: Sorry, i mean it works for 1 or 2 line /*comment*/ but not for more. In my example i've got a /* at the 2 line and the next */ is at the 5 line so it suppose to take everything from /* to */

Comment: some modification to it now try : \/\*((.)*(\n)?)*(.)*\\*\/ this should work